# Installing Community Engine for Rails 4 with Github Source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I wanted to utilize CommunityEngine for a social network project of mine and I'm doing it in Rails 4, now upon looking at their documentation here (for Rails4 branch):
https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/tree/rails4

I then followed step 1 which is to put this line to my GemFile:
gem  "https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git", :branch => "rails4"

Also step 2 on configuring app name... Now the problem is when I do "bundle install"

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'communityengine (>= 0) ruby' in
https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git (at rails4).
Source does not contain any versions of 'communityengine (>= 0) ruby'
```

How do I enable to install the communityengine gem in my rails 4 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To point to github repo for a gem you need to do:

```
gem 'community_engine', git: 'https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git', branch: 'rails4'
```

I have submitted pull request for the change in the documentation for this branch.

Comment: I was about to say that I'd tried it.. but the difference is that I used gem 'communityengine' .. now this one works, but I just had to specify rails to 4.0.0 .. I wonder if they could update it to use Rails 4.0.0 and above.. as well as the gem dependencies.